# Angular Primeng: Create Observable from lazyLoad event

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, primeng, primeng-datatable

I've coded this html:

```
<p-table #usersTable ...>
<p-table>
```

I'm trying to pick up this element in order to create an observable on `onLazyLoad` event:

```
@ViewChild('usersTable')
private usersTable: ElementRef;
```

In order to create observable:

```
public ngAfterViewInit() {
    let lazyTable$ = Observable
        .fromEvent(this.usersTable.nativeElement, 'onLazyLoad')
        .pipe(debounceTime(300));
}
```

Nevertheless, `this.usersTable` is undefined.

By other hand, I not sure at all, of having observable event creation correctly.

I've used

```
@ViewChildren(DataTable) private usersTable: QueryList<DataTable>;
```

Nevertheless, when a change is made `query.length` is always 0:

```
let lazyClick$ = this.usersTable.changes
    .pipe(
        filter((query: QueryList<DataTable>) => {
            return query.length > 0;
        }),
        map((query: QueryList<DataTable>) => {
            return query.first;
        }),
        switchMap((table) => {
            return table.onLazyLoad.asObservable();
        })
    );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using angular > v8? is the <p-table #usersTable ...> inside some *structural directive?

Comment: Yes, it's inside an `div *ngIf`, and when parent component is loaded ngIf is false. I'm using angular 4.

Comment: Do you have more than one table?

Comment: No... but sometines `ngIf` is true and sometimes is false (when is there no results to show). I need to pick table each time is visisble...

Comment: In that case you can check the `usersTable` variable, I'v updated my answer to show you

Comment: Only one final issue. It doesn't work if I use `@ViewChild(DataTable)` instead of `@ViewChild('usersTable')`. Why?

Comment: Try `@ViewChild(DataTable) set content(usersTable: DataTable)`

Answer (score 1):

Has you've comment that your table is inside a div with an `*ngIf`, you can use `set content` to get the reference for your table.

```
@ViewChild('usersTable') set content(usersTable: ElementRef) {
  if (usersTable) {
    let lazyTable$ = Observable
        .fromEvent(this.usersTable.nativeElement, 'onLazyLoad')
        .pipe(debounceTime(300));
  }
}
```

This way, this function will execute on each change to `*ngIf` condition change, meaning when your table gets shown or hidden.

Comment: I've changed my post. Could you help out?

Answer (score 1):

I can Create Observable from lazyLoad event like this.

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

  @ViewChild('usersTable') set content(usersTable: Table) {
    if (usersTable) {
      let lazyTable$ = usersTable.onLazyLoad.pipe(debounceTime(300));
      }
    }
```